# How to use Android S builds the AOSP Android jars for Robolectric?

Tags: java, android, android-source, robolectric

My work need to use some hiden Api. I want to know how can we build a jar lilkes android-all-10-robolectric-5803371.jar for Android S, I saw some scripts shell here https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/scripts/build-android.sh ,but its doesn't show how to build a jar for Android S. Does any one knows how to do it? I would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have known the command to build those jars from AOSP. The answer is at https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/6886#issuecomment-987681840: `m -j8 robolectric-host-android_all`.